# Change Form1.Checkbox state on Form2.Disposed event

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have been searching for a solution of this particular problem for some hours now. So you kind people of Stackoverflow are my last resort

Here is what i've done so far

---

this is in Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 newForm1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
     private void Form2_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      newForm1 = new Form1();
      newForm1.CheckBox1_Checked = false;
    }
```

---

this is in Form2.Designer.cs

```
partial class Form2
{
   ....
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      ....
      this.Disposed += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Disposed);
      ....
    }
   ....
}
```

---

this is in Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  ....
  public bool CheckBox1_Checked
  {
      get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
      set { checkBox1.Checked = value; }
  }
  ....
}
```

So when I close Form2 (with X) the program goes through the Disposed event but does not change the Checkbox state.

I've also tried to make the Form1.Checkbox1 control public and access it directly (i mean without the use of accessors, but still no luck.

I suspect the newForm1 is a copy of the Form1. 
But i don't know how to tell that "newForm1" is the very "Form1" object

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: form1 is already opened?

Comment: Yes @irsog form1 is already opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Form1 is already opened you can do this:(instead of using Dispose use closed event)
Form1.cs

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Form1 = this;
        }
        public static Form1 _Form1;

        public CheckBox chk { get { return checkBox1; } }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 gg = new Form2();
            gg.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form2_FormClosed);
        }

        void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1._Form1.chk.Checked = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1Instance;
    ...

    Form1.OnLoad(...)
    {
        Form1Instance=this;
    }
}

//now call using static variable
Form1.Form1Instance.CheckBox1_Checked=true;
```

Comment: You 'd better call this in Form2.OnClose(), rather than Form2.Dispose();

Comment: Thanks @David from now on you are my personal God.
And i shall sacrifice a beer in your honor tonight :D